# Кто такой бельмес?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Говорят, что кто-то "ни бельмеса не смыслит". А кто такой, собственно, бельмес?
Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Бельмес - это интересное слово. Оно заимствовано из тюркских, но по принципу "звукоподражания", значение напрямую не связано со значением в языке-источнике. 
Кажется, есть для таких слов особый термин - но не помню, может кто подскажет.
Изначально оно употреблялось только в отношении знания языка, потом несколько расширило смысл.
История такова. При общении русских с представителями местного населениея тюркоязычных областей те частенько отвечали "бильмэз" - "не знаю (языка)", "не понимаю".  Отсюда и родился этот "бельмес".

(---------)
*бельме́с только в выражении ни бельме́са не понима́ет. Из тат., тур. bilmäs "он не будет знать" (от bilmäk) или тур. bilmäz "несведущий"; см. Корш, AfslPh 9, 491; Бернекер 1, 40; Шёльд, ZfslPh 5, 392.*
Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер. 1964—1973.

Comment: Выражение  это  может  звучать  и  так:  я  не  бельмес !  В  значении  ничего  в  чём-то  не  знаю.  Или  просто:  не  бельмес !  В  ответ  на  чей-нибудь  вопрос.

Comment: Не слышал такого варианта.